# Return data from a screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two screens. I want a number to be returned from the second screen.

> Navigator.pop(context, numder )

How can I make a handler on the first screen?

Comment: Take a look at Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get return value with pop on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539269/how-to-get-return-value-with-pop-on-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to push like this when you want to receive data from next screen:

```
onPressed: ()async {
    var result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
    
    if(result != null){
       print(result);
    }
}
```

by say like this way, I mean call `await` can return to a variable, not exactly this `push`.

Comment: Can I add this to the onPressed() of the button?

Comment: I updated my answer for that.